# How to change auth model for tenant? e.g. if using breeze

Tags: php, laravel

Hi i use laravel 10 with tenancy for laravel, i have two connection, and for my central database i use users model its fine with default connection, but for tenancy i use second connection to retrive data from server ( but not everytime , here i use both conn ) which second connection have the accounts table ( game database), and i want to make session from account. In reast everything is fine but i dont know how to change the providers model to switch from users to accounts..

I want to use for example in breeze auth package account model not users..

I did this but its work just if i make login ( succesfully ) but when i try to do logout ( just logout i tried ), he tried to select from users model.. So i'm sure i did something wrong.. or maybe everything is wrong

i change the config/auth and i created an middleware (declare in kernel.php for tenant group):

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'tenant' => [
            'driver' => 'session', 
            'provider' => 'accounts', 
        ],
    ],

'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        'accounts' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Tenant\Account::class, 
        ],
    ],

class SwitchAuthModel
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        config(['auth.guards.web' => config('auth.guards.tenant')]);
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by making a custom login for the tenant users.

**auth.php**

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => env('GUARD_CONNECTION','users'),
    ],

    'tenant' => [
        'driver'   => 'session',
        'provider' => 'tenant_users',
    ]
],
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],

    'tenant_users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model'  => App\Models\Tenant\User::class,
    ],
],
```

Helper function that returns guard **tenant** or **web**

```
if (!function_exists('guard')) {
 function guard(): string
 {
    return tenant('id') ? 'tenant' : 'web';
 }
}
```

Custom Login Controller Method For Tenant Users

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    if ( Auth::guard(guard())->attempt(['email' => $request->input('email'), 'password' => $request->input('password')])) {
        dump('tenant user login');
    }
}
```

For tenant users just add a guard with auth middleware like **auth:tenant**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:tenant', 'prefix' => 'modals'], function () {
  Route::get('{type}/{itemId?}', [ModalController::class, 'show'] )->name('modal.show');
});
```

Comment: So i did some mistakes.. i saw in guards i didn't write guards correctly, i fixed in auth ` 'guards' => [
//web
        'tenant' => [
            'driver' => 'session', 
            'provider' => 'accounts', 
        ],
    ],

'providers' => [
//users

        'accounts' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Tenant\Account::class, 
],
    ],
` but with that middleware which change the config .. for login is work but i dont know why for logout searching from users table.. not from account

Comment: I dont know why if i call /logout  on get method .. he searching this select * from `users` where `id` = 11361 and `users`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 he didnt enter to my controller to execute Auth::logout();

Comment: Maybe you need to create a separate route for that to execute your logout.

Comment: I think i fixed , in InitializeTenancyByDomain  ( that i use for tenancy initialized ) i put in constructor this Auth::setDefaultDriver('tenant'); // Set the default guard to 'tenant_user' Auth::shouldUse('tenant'); .. and i saw its work, i need just to set the database config conection because in middleware i dont know why he didnt initialized ( for logout just for logout i checked... )

Answer (score 0):

I fixed..

in my **InitializeTenancyByDomain** i put this in **__construct**

```
Auth::setDefaultDriver('tenant'); // Set the default guard to 'tenant_user'
Auth::shouldUse('tenant');
```

and you need to create a new auth middleware for tenant.

Best regards,
Alex.